# Cadastro de pessoa usando várias viewModels e apenas uma controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Quero fazer um cadastro de uma pessoa, que dividi em três entidades: Pessoa, Contato e Endereço. E quero que seja apenas um formulário de cadastro.

Minha action create na controller de pessoa está assim:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(PessoaViewModel pessoaViewModel)
    {
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            pessoaViewModel = _pessoaAppService.Adicionar(pessoaViewModel);          
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(pessoaViewModel);
    }
```

Método Adicionar na camada de Aplicação:

```
public PessoaViewModel Adicionar(PessoaViewModel pessoaViewModel)
    {
        var pessoa = Mapper.Map<PessoaViewModel, Pessoa>(pessoaViewModel);

         BeginTransaction();

        var pessoaValidacao = _pessoaService.Adicionar(pessoa);
        pessoaViewModel = Mapper.Map<Pessoa, PessoaViewModel>(pessoaValidacao);

        Commit();

        return pessoaViewModel;

    }
```

Adicionar na camada de Domínio:

```
 public Pessoa Adicionar(Pessoa pessoa)
    {
        return _pessoaRepositorio.Adicionar(pessoa);
    }
```

Repositório genérico:

```
 public virtual TEntity Adicionar(TEntity obj)
    {
       return DbSet.Add(obj);
    }
```

E eu tenho algumas partials views que fazem o formulário:

```
          <!-- todo o formulario-->
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="tab-content">

                    <!-- primeira aba -->
                    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane active">
                        @Html.Partial("_DadosCadastrais")
                    </div>

                    <!-- segunda aba -->
                    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane">
                        @Html.Partial("_Contato")
                    </div>

                    <!-- terceira aba -->
                    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane">
                        @Html.Partial("_EnderecoPessoa")
                    </div>

                </div>
```

e cada partial view usa um viewModel diferente:

contato:

```
@model V1.Aplicacao.ViewModels.PessoaContatoViewModel
```

Endereco:

```
@model V1.Aplicacao.ViewModels.EnderecoViewModel
```

Pessoa:

```
@model V1.Aplicacao.ViewModels.PessoaViewModel
```

Como faço para poder usar o método de create de pessoa para cadastrar essas três entidades no banco?

Comment: Você tem 1 objeto pessoa, e dentro dele coloca os outros 2 objetos que quer passar da view para o controller, depois só cadastrar.Pelo que eu entendi pode ser feito assim.

Comment: PessoaViewModel  pode ser composta de PessoaContatoViewModel, EnderecoViewModel e PessoaViewModel. Utilize essas propriedades de PessoaViewModel   nas partials.

Comment: Sim fiz isso, Mas e ai na minha classe de PessoaAppService, que converte a viewModel para entidade, como eu faço? ficaria algo do tipo : `var endereco = Mapper.Map<PessoaViewModel, Endereco>(PessoaViewModel); Pessoa.Enderecos.Add(endereco);`  Ou não é preciso fazer isso?

Comment: Vai ser necessário declarar as regras de mapeamento de PessoaContatoViewModel, EnderecoViewModel e PessoaViewModel antes da regra de PessoaViewModel. Assim, o Automapper saberá utilizá-las.

Answer (score 5):

Você está usando errado o Entity Framework. É uma ótima oportunidade pra mostrar porque é uma **péssima** ideia implementar um repositório genérico e/ou camada de serviço.

Isto:

```
public PessoaViewModel Adicionar(PessoaViewModel pessoaViewModel)
{
    var pessoa = Mapper.Map<PessoaViewModel, Pessoa>(pessoaViewModel);

    BeginTransaction();

    var pessoaValidacao = _pessoaService.Adicionar(pessoa);
    pessoaViewModel = Mapper.Map<Pessoa, PessoaViewModel>(pessoaValidacao);

    Commit();

    return pessoaViewModel;
}
```

Subaproveita o Entity Framework, que utiliza [`TransactionScope`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) para abarcar todas as operações de uma transação.

Não sei onde está seu contexto, mas a maneira correta de persistir uma série de dados com suporte a *rollback* é assim:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) 
{
    var pessoa = new Pessoa 
    {
        // Converta os campos de PessoaViewModel aqui, ou use alguma
        // outra técnica que preferir. Particularmente não gosto de 
        // AutoMapper.
    };

    context.Pessoas.Add(pessoa);
    context.SaveChanges();

    var pessoaContato = new PessoaContato
    {
        // Mesma coisa aqui, com o seguinte:
        Pessoa = pessoa
    };        

    context.PessoasContatos.Add(pessoaContato);
    context.SaveChanges();

    var endereco = new Endereco
    {
        // Idem
        Pessoa = pessoa
    };        

    context.Enderecos.Add(endereco);
    context.SaveChanges();

    scope.Complete();
}
```

Ainda que você possa dizer que este código pode ser encapsulado e reusado, **não há a menor necessidade disso**, até porque não consigo imaginar outro *Controller* que também insira uma pessoa com mais 2 entidades agregadas.

Comment: Faz pouco tempo que eu comecei a estudar C#, entity, mvc, etc... tem muita coisa que eu ainda não peguei bem, mas eu entendi o modo que você fez, só não entendi bem por que é uma péssima ideia usar repositório genérico, se eu tivesse muitas tabelas no banco e não usasse o repositório genérico, eu teria que fazer um pra cada entidade que eu tivesse no banco, isso não seria um pouco de repetição de código? Eu vou dar uma estudada nisso tudo e no transactionScope, os tutoriais que encontro na internet são meio confusos as vezes, e obrigado pela orientação.

Comment: @Aesir O Entity Framework já implementa um repositório. Você não precisa implementar outro. [Veja quantas vezes já precisei falar isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+entity+framework+reposit%C3%B3rio).

Answer (score 3):

Um **ViewModel** representa um conjunto de uma ou mais **Models** e outros dados que serão representados em uma **View** que necessita exibir determinado conjunto de informações.

Então, você pode aproveitar e utilizar PessoaViewModel para contemplar as informações de Contato e Endereco que você quer salvar.

```
public class PessoaViewModel
{
   //Todas as propriedades de Pessoa que você deseja utilizar na View...

   //Informações de Endereço...
   public EnderecoViewModel Endereco { get; set; }

   //Informações de Contato...
   public PessoaContatoViewModel Contato { get; set; }
}
```

Sua View deve ser tipada conforme seu Model, no caso **PessoaViewModel** (que agora contempla os dados de Endereco e Contato), para que você possa acessar todas as informações:

```
@model ...PessoaViewModel

<html>
    <body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @* seu código da view *@...               
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

No seu Controller, sua action de Post continua a receber um objeto do seu PessoaViewModel:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(PessoaViewModel pessoaViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        //Através do objeto pessoaViewModel, você obtem os dados informados 
        //de Pessoa, Endereço e Contato para monta os objetos que deseja salvar.                    
        ...
    } 
    ...
}
```

---

**Edição:**

Conforme dúvida do seu comentário "*Eu não sei como fazer para retirar os dados de contato e endreço da pessoaViewModel e salvar no banco*":

No seu *Controller*, você vai receber no parâmetro **pessoaViewModel** todos os dados da página de cadastro, logo, para obter os dados de contato utilize `pessoaViewModel.Contato` e `pessoaViewModel.Endereco` para obter os dados de endereço.

Ex:

//Crie um método para te retornar uma nova pessoa

```
var novaPessoa = _pessoaService.CriarPessoa(pessoaViewModel.Nome, pessoaViewModel.Contato, pessoaViewModel.Endereco);
```

//Salve a pessoa

```
var pessoaValidacao = _pessoaService.Adicionar(novaPessoa);
```

Comment: Mas e ai na minha classe  de PessoaAppService, que converte a viewModel para entidade, como eu faço? ficaria algo do tipo :                                      `var endereco = Mapper.Map<PessoaViewModel, Endereco>(PessoaViewModel);    Pessoa.Enderecos.Add(endereco);`

Comment: Desculpe, não me atentei ao mapeamento que você está utilizando, até mesmo porque não foi dada a estrutura do objeto Pessoa. Ocorreu erro ao mapear Pessoa/PessoaViewModel? Qual a mensagem de erro? Tem como você adicionar sua classe Pessoa, uma vez que eh necessário saber a estrutura dessa classe para tentarmos ajudá-lo no mapeamento?

Comment: Eu fiz como você falou, coloquei as propriedades que irei usar e depois **endereco** e **contato**, ela ficou muito grande para mostrar aqui, pois eu resumi a pergunta.. Não deu nem um erro, mas não está salvando em endereço e contato. Eu não sei como fazer para retirar os dados de contato e endreço da pessoaViewModel e salvar no banco;