# C# Entity DbSet com DDD?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ddd

Tenho uma aplicação `C#` `MVC` com `DDD` e na `repository` estou fazendo a chamada assim:

```
 return DbSet.Include(i => i.Cliente).FirstOrDefault(a => a.ProcessoId == processoId);
```

`DbSet->` está no `repositoy` de Processo

```
public class Processo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Obs { get; set; }  <- varchar(max)
    public int? ClienteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

**Dúvidas:**

Utilizando o `DbSet` é possível ignorar o campo `Obs`, no retorno da consulta?

(ou seja ao invés de fazer `SELECT * seja feito SELECT Id, ClienteId, ... Join...`)

Alguém conhece alguma outra forma de fazer isso e manter o include?

Algum componente, projeto semelhante, sugestões serão bem vindas.

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiquei em dúvidas em alguns campos, mas, pode ser feito o `Include`, após um `Select` e por fim o filtro dentro do `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var result = DbSet
      .Include(i = i.Cliente)
      .Select(s => new {
          s.Id, 
          s.ClienteId,
          s.Cliente
      })
      .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == processoId);
```

nesse caso especifico a variável `result` é um tipo anônimo (`desconhecido`). Se quiser retornar um tipo especifico (*Fortemente Tipado*), crie um `classe` que represente esse resultado, exemplo:

```
public class ProcessoViewModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int? ClienteId {get;set;}
    public Cliente Cliente {get;set;
}
```

---

Faça a alteração no código:

```
ProcessoViewModel result = DbSet
      .Include(i = i.Cliente)
      .Select(s => new ProcessoViewModel
      {
          Id = s.Id, 
          ClienteId = s.ClienteId,
          Cliente = s.Cliente
      })
      .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == processoId);
```

Algumas ***resposta*** que podem te auxiliar:

- [Cadastro de pessoa usando várias viewModels e apenas uma controller](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75737/cadastro-de-pessoa-usando-v%C3%A1rias-viewmodels-e-apenas-uma-controller)
- [Utilização de DTO e ViewModel em projeto ASP.Net MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33005/utiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-dto-e-viewmodel-em-projeto-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: mas assim retornará objeto generic, para retornar Processo

deve ter um new Processo{}

Comment: @MarcoViniciusSoaresDalalba é verdade ele vai gerar um tipo anônimo, e não genérico, um tipo criado em tempo de execução, já que o usuário quer desconsiderar um campo da sua classe.

Comment: A solução acima é boa, para objetos pequenos.
Quando eu tiver um objeto muito grande fica complicado dar manutenção, até mesmo quando adicionar novas propriedades (quando trabalhar em grupo que é o meu caso), por isso estou pensando no contrario, informar os campos que não quero carregar no meu objeto de retorno seja este genérico ou não.

Comment: @nfrigo por isso foi adicionado duas formas possíveis. Dependendo do caso escolha uma delas ...